# How to set JQuery .show / .hide without repeating Div selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, dry

I want to pass this function a True or a False and have the elements listed show (true) or hide (false) on this input.

I am currently using this function...

```
        function SetElementVisibility(visible) {
        if (visible) {
            $("#Div1").show("slow");
            $("#Div2").show("slow");
            $("#Div3").show("slow");
        }
        else {
            $("#Div1").hide("slow");
            $("#Div2").hide("slow");
            $("#Div3").hide("slow");
        }
    }
```

But i would prefer to not repeat myself by naming the Div's for each outcome.

How can i refactor this into a more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) example?

Thanks,
Kohan

Comment: Javascript doesn't listen to DRY.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use square-bracket notation to pick a method name depending on the `visible` variable:

```
$('#Div1, #Div2, #Div3')[visible? 'show' : 'hide']('slow');
```

Comment: Since this is what i used, and you got in with the answer, a whopping 1 minute before. You get the Tick :)

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
function SetElementVisibility(visible) {
   $("#Div1,#Div2,#Div3")[visible]("slow");
}

// Display all
SetElementVisibility( "show" );

// Hide all
SetElementVisibility( "hide" );
```

If you dont want to use `"show"` and `"hide"` as arguments but `true` and `false` you would have to change it a little bit:

```
function SetElementVisibility(visible) {
   $("#Div1,#Div2,#Div3")[visible?'show':'hide']("slow");
}

// Display all
SetElementVisibility( true );

// Hide all
SetElementVisibility( false );
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like $("#Div1, #Div2, #Div3").show(...

See [this](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for more information...

Answer (score 1):

use this method:

```
$("ID").toggle()
```

Try using class instead of id. For example:

```
function SetElementVisibility(visible) {
    if (visible) {
        $(".showHideDiv").show("slow");
    }
    else {
        $(".showHideDiv").hide("slow");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not going to be "slow" :)

Answer (score 1):

you can improve this

```
if(..)
$('[id^=Div]').show();
else
$('[id^=Div]').hide();
```

if you keep this div start with same id prefix !

Comment: This will be slow if you got a biiiiig dom.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways:

```
$('#Div1, #Div2, #Div3').hide('slow');
```

or

```
$('#Div1').add('#Div2').add('#Div3').hide('slow');
```

or

```
$.each(['#Div1', '#Div2', '#Div3'], function(i,v){
    $(v).hide('slow');
});
```

Well ok, the third looks a little bit alien but whatever.

If all those desired `divs` really start with `Div` you may also use

```
$('div[id=^Div]').hide('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
function SetElementVisibility(visible) {
    $elements =  $("#Div1, #Div2, #Div3");
    if (visible) {
        $elements.show("slow");
    }
    else {
        $elements.hide("slow");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will replace with

```
 function SetElementVisibility() {
       $('#Div1,#Div2,#Div3').toggle();
}
```

Comment: This will give different results... imagine he calls like this: `SetElementVisibility(true); SetElementVisibility(true); SetElementVisibility(true); SetElementVisibility(false); SetElementVisibility(true); SetElementVisibility(true); `.  He would have to re-write the rest of his system to use your function.